# Audio shuts off when PC locks in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Is there anyway to prevent Windows 8 from cutting off the audio when it locks?

My power plan settings are to shut off the monitor after 10 min and never put the computer to sleep.

Thanks.

Comment: Shutting the monitor should not lock the computer nor should locking the computer shut the audio on your system.  I attempted this test on a virtual machine using the default installation settings for Windows 8 using a standard user with regular user permissions.

Comment: It does though.  The audio is coming from a browser though, I wonder if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to this. It is caused by an advanced power setting controlling the timeout of the console lock screen.

You have to perform a registry edit to enable the option to be controlled by the Advanced Power Settings GUI.

> To enable the setting under Display for Advanced Power Options, do the following registry change 
>   under
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7`
>
> Change Attributes from 1 to 2

From there change the Display -> Console Lock Display Off Timeout setting from its default of 1 minute to 0 for never, or whatever setting you desire.

[Source](http://blog.escarra.org/?p=110)